# MS Flow to Email User if Certain Date Column is Equal to Today's Date

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

So I have a document library with a view that only shows files/trainings pertaining to each individual.

There is a Person or Group column called "Player" where I have the list view filter set to only show items when Player is equal to [Me]. There is another column "RetentionDate" which is calculated to represent a date 1 year after the user has uploaded and completed the file they are uploading.

Currently in my flow, I have a get items action to read the files from the document library. What I want to do next is if the current Date is equal the RetentionDate, or even 30 days before that date, to send an email to that user with a notification and reminder.

**UPDATE**

So I tried what I had mentioned above. I currently have 7 documents 6 of which have Retention Dates in December 2022, and one that has the retention date of today 12/6/2021. From my understanding, if all of the logic is correct in my flow, I should only get one email, but instead, I am getting 5 emails?.

[image]

Here is the condition I am using:

`RetentionDate` is greater than or equal to `formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'MM/DD/YYYY')`

Answer (score 0):

Its your condition that is the issue. It will give you every documnt with a retention date greater that today. The condition should be

RetentionDate is equal to formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'MM/DD/YYYY')

You might need to also set the RetentionDate with formatDateTime in case that field includes timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with RuneBH, this may be because the **[RetentionDate]** field contains a `timestamp`.

**Please follow the steps:**

1. In my test, **[RetentionDate]** is a **Calculated column** that calculates the value of  [Created] plus [Days to review]

[image]

[image]

**2.Here is my Microsoft Flow:**

[image]

3.Save & Test flow

[image]

[image]